# Removing a value of a linked struct

Tags: c, list, struct, linked-list

The function has to return the address of linked list after removing the requested value of it if founded, else to return a NULL, function
 search(int input, CellPtr list) works very well...
the actuall output of the program is right untill it reaches the second function actually it doesn't print anything

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct cell *CellPtr;
typedef struct cell {
    int contents;
    CellPtr next;
}   Cell;
int search(int input, CellPtr list);
CellPtr delete_cell(int input, CellPtr list);
int main()
{
    CellPtr list;
    list = malloc(sizeof(Cell));
    list->contents = -2;                                /*ONLY FOR TESTING*/
    list->next = malloc(sizeof(Cell));
    list->next->contents = 4;
    list->next->next = malloc(sizeof(Cell));
    list->next->next->contents = -6;
    list->next->next->next = malloc(sizeof(Cell));
    list->next->next->next->contents = 100;
    printf("search(100, list) = %d\n", search(-6, list));
    if (list = delete_cell(-5, list) == NULL)
        printf("not found");
    return 0;
}

CellPtr delete_cell(int input, CellPtr list)
{
    int i, j;
    CellPtr p, q, tmp;
    if (i = search(input, list) == 0)   {
        return NULL;
    }
    p = list;
    if (i == 1) {
        list = p->next;
        free(p);
        return list;
    }
    for (j=1; j<i-1; j++)   {
        p = p->next;                            /*to get the address of the cell pointing to wanted cell*/
    }
    if (p->next->next == NULL)  {               /*wanted cell is the last one in the list*/
        free(p->next);
        p->next = NULL;
        return list;
    }
    q = p->next;
    while (q->next->next != NULL)   {           /*q is the address of the cell one before the last cell*/
        q = q->next;
    }
    if ((input * list->contents > 0) && (input * q->next->contents < 0))  {
        tmp = list;
        list = tmp->next;
        tmp->next = p->next->next;
        free(p->next);
        p->next = tmp;
        return list;
    }
    if ((input * list->contents <0) && (input * q->next->contents > 0)) {
        q->next->next = p->next->next;
        free(p->next);
        p->next = q->next;
        q->next = NULL;
        return list;
    }
    if ((input * list->contents >0) && (input * q->next->contents > 0)) {
        q->next->next = p->next->next;
        free(p->next);
        p->next = q->next;
        q->next = NULL;
        return list;
    }
    if ((input * list->contents <0) && (input * q->next->contents < 0)) {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: the code is quite hard to follow. Does it look for the value "input" and delete the Cell node?

Comment: One possible issue is, `list = delete_cell(-5, list) == NULL`, is it `(list=delete_cell(-5,list) == NULL` or `list = (delete_cell(-5,list)==NULL)`? Without parenthesis, it means later one.

Answer (score 1):

Here, when you initialize the last element:

```
list->next->next->next = malloc(sizeof(Cell));
```

you miss to initialize its `next`-pointer to NULL. You have to add:

```
list->next->next->next->next = NULL;
```

Otherwise, a function searching for a non-existant element (as in `delete_cell(-5, list)` will dereference an uninitialized pointer and the programm will probably crash (undefined behaviour).